# Different behaviour based on move constructor

Tags: c++, struct, move

I have a piece of code to check if `move` happened.

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo() = default;
  Foo(Foo&& other) = default;

  double a[1000];
  double b[1000];
};

Foo giveMe()
{
  Foo ret;
  std::cout << &ret << std::endl;

  return ret;
}

int main()
{
  Foo o1 = giveMe();
  std::cout << &o1 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Well, it does not. The addresses of `ret` and `o1` are, for instance, as follows:

```
008F7D78
008FBC08
```

However, after slight change in move constructor:

```
struct Foo
{
  Foo() = default;
  Foo(Foo&& other) {}

  double a[1000];
  double b[1000];
};
```

the addressees are the same:

```
010FBE28
010FBE28
```

What is happening here? I assume that this behaviour is somehow related to `POD` or `trivial` types but I am not sure how.

Comment: "Moving" means to move resources from one instance to another. Not to move an instance to another memory address.

Comment: @churill I am aware of it. The address check is there just to see if move or copy happened.

Comment: It depends on the compiler and compiles flags.

Comment: You are looking for copy elision. Are you in C++17?

Comment: *"after slight change"* first snippet move (so copy for this type) members whereas second snippet doesn't initialize members.

Comment: I am guessing you use MSVC. GCC and Clang elide "big objects" too, despite the allowance described in the dupe

Comment: I am truly using MSVC. The answer in the linked question, thanks for your time guys!

Comment: @tucna I think you have a slight misconception about moving. Imagine `Foo a; Foo b(std::move(a));` this would call the move-ctor but both objects will have distinct and constant addresses. And consider that static arrays can never be moved, but only copied, so your move-ctor does just the same as the copy-ctor.

Comment: @churill I agree with your statements, however I am not sure if we talk about the same thing. How can you explain the different/same addresses, then?

Comment: @tucna Basically the compiler recognizes that `ret` will eventually be copied into `o1` and that `ret` will cease to exist. So the compiler elides the copy by writing directly to the `o1`. In one case it doesn't apply this optimization, that's what should be covered in the dupe.

Answer (score 0):

> What is happening here?

Optimisation is happpening here. More precisely: Named Return Value Optimisation (NRVO).

Even though the abstract machine moves in both cases, NRVO optimised (elided) the move away from the second example.

> The address check is there just to see if move or copy happened.

The class isn't copyable, so a copy can't have happened. Also, the address check cannot distinguish between copied and moved object. Either would have a different address.

To clarify a possible misconception: "Move" construction creates a new object using the move constructor. That new object typically has a different address than the object that was moved from, just like when copying. The only case where the address of the new object is the same is when the move is optimised away such that the constructor is never actually called (which can also be done with copies).